# Read a single character or byte from stdIn without waiting for newline in SML

Tags: input, functional-programming, byte, buffer, sml

I encountered a problem while working with the TextIO structure,
because every input waites for a newline chacter and for the buffer to be full...
How can i work with BinIO and stdIn to solve that problem?

Any helpfull input is appreciated.

BTW: I am using MLTton so there is nothing more than the usual standard libs.

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, you could write it yourself in C, and then call it from SML using the foreign function interface.  You can find out more info about MLton's FFI here: http://mlton.org/ForeignFunctionInterface

Answer (score 0):

> I encountered a problem while working with the TextIO structure, because every input waites for a newline chacter and for the buffer to be full... How can i work with BinIO and stdIn to solve that problem?

`BinIO`, like `TextIO`, implements *buffered* I/O. (They both implement the `IMPERATIVE_IO` signature.) For *unbuffered* I/O, you need to go "down" a level in abstraction, and use an implementation of `PRIMITIVE_IO` or `POSIX_IO`.

Specifically, `Posix.IO.readVec` lets you read unbufferedly from a file descriptor. (In the case of standard input, the file descriptor is `Posix.FileSys.stdin`.)

However, if your standard input is from the console (as opposed to being redirected from a file, or taken from a pipe, or whatnot), then there's a very good chance that the console only provides input *to* MLton after the user hits Enter. Using `Posix.IO` will bypass the line-buffering functionality that MLton provides, but if you also need to bypass your console's line buffering, then you'll likely need to use special C libraries (specific to your operating system), with the foreign function interface that Matt mentions in his answer.